# Create New ContentFolderMember or ContentFolderLink through SOAP or Rest?

Tags: soql, rest-api, soap-api

I'm getting errors creating both the `ContentFolderMember` and the `ContentFolderLink` objects from the new "Summer of 15" SOAP api.

I am a Library Admin and I have been able to create the new ContentFolder objects through SOAP.  I'm using the force-wsc Soap api.

The Object Reference for Salesforce documentation ver 34:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/object_reference.pdf
mentions that the create() call does not support either of the ContentFolderMember and ContentFolderLink objects.

I'm assuming these two objects are similar to the 
`ContentWorkspaceDoc` which is a link object between the `ContentDocument` and `ContentWorkspace`.  The `ContentWorkspaceDoc` is also not creatable, but is automatically created when you set the `FirstPublishLocationId` on a new `ContentVersion` to a existing `ContentWorkspaceId`.

**For the ContentFolderLink:**

I’ve tried

- setting the `ContentVersion.FirstPublishLocationId` to an existing
  `ContentFolder.Id`
- also tried setting a `ContentDocument.ParentId` to
  an existing `ContentWorkspace.Id`

neither of these work

**For the ContentFolderMember:**

- I’ve tried setting an existing `ContentFolder.ParentContentFolderId`
  to a `ContentWorkspace.Id` without luck.

Anyone been able to link a`ContentDocument` to a `ContentFolder` or link a `ContentFolder` to `ContentWorkspace`?

Comment: We had a case open with Salesforce to get an answer on this. The gist of the response was that ContentFolderLink and ContentFolderMember were released incomplete in API 34. There will be no fix/update in this release and the create/update/delete permissions will be available in a future release along with UI updates (Safe harbor next release).